# Existence of Holomorphic functions on the open unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a holomorphic function f from the open unit disc into itself such that f(1/2) = 0 and f(1/3) = 1/4.

Schwarz Lemma doesn't seem to be of help . I guess i am missing some element that's needed to solve this question.

Another question is does such a function f exist on the open unit disc such that f(0) = M, and f(M) = 0, where M is nonzero.

Comment: Lookup “Schwarz Pick Theorem.” (This must have been asked and answered before.)

Comment: A very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2053803/42969. The same approach works in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I appreciate it. These two are solved. I have a followup question though. 

Does such a holomorphic  f  exist such that f(0) = 0 and f(1/3) = 0.  Clearly, Schwarz Lemma, and the Pick Lemma aren't violated. If there does exist, what is one such f written explicitly?

Comment: Look for “Finite Blaschke products” in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product